# unable to scrape information from this website using php

Tags: php, curl

I tried to scrape information from this site: http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/viewHtml?e=2745298

However, when i try to echo $output, something don't seem right and it redirects to localhost site (http://localhost/FileAccess/viewHtml?e=2745298)

my source as below

```html
        function curl_download($Url){
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $start = strpos($output, '<html>');
        $end = strpos($output, '</html>', $start);

        $length = $end-$start;
        $output = substr($output, $start, $length);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        echo $output;
        
        }
```

Comment: the page contents contain a javascript redirector, you need to print the output as a special characters instead

Comment: Hi Hassan, replacing **echo $output** to **print $output**?  I had tried that and it still redirect

Comment: `echo htmlspecialchars($output);`

Comment: Hi, i think i had been too careless. When i take 2nd look on the echo results, it didn't match the original output value

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
    function curl_download($Url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $start = strpos($output, '<html>');
    $end = strpos($output, '</html>', $start);

    $length = $end-$start;
    $output = substr($output, $start, $length);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;

    }
```

Comment: why he had to `Use following` ? it's always be better to provide more explanation with your solution

Comment: however the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` options is to follow the HTTP redirection , not javascript or client side redirections

Comment: he hasnt added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION so its redirecting to localhost.

Comment: i actually added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, but the redirect still persist, therefore i'd removed it.